Handling Large Datasets in initState() in Flutter
If I fetch a large amount of data in initState(), will it affect my app's performance? How should I handle a large dataset efficiently?
I am working on a Flutter application and I am concerned about the performance implications of fetching a large dataset from the database in the initState() method. Here is my current implementation:
 void initState() {
     super.initState();
     WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     Provider.of<DealerProvider>(context, listen: false).fetchDealers();
 });
}

Problem:
fetchDealers() retrieves a large dataset from the database. I am worried that this might impact my app's performance, causing slow load times or unresponsiveness.
Questions:
Will fetching a large dataset in initState() affect my app's performance?
How can I handle large datasets more efficiently?
Should I limit the number of records fetched in initState() and load additional data only when users scroll down the screen?
What I Tried:
I implemented data fetching in the initState() method as shown above. My expectation was that the data would load and populate the UI once the widget was built. However, I am concerned that this approach might lead to performance issues, especially with large datasets.
I am considering implementing pagination or lazy loading to handle the data more efficiently.

"I'm worried...", "I'm concerned...". Haven't you tested it? Hard to respond to a problem that might not be a problem at all... Once you have concrete numbers and share the context, valuable answers/suggestions might be given.

One thing is sure, initState is not really meant to perform async operations. I would suggest using a FutureBuilder in the build method instead. Of course it will not help if the fetch takes too much time.
